# Google GeoChart not working for state level with displayMode to regions

Tags: geolocation, google-visualization

I'm building a simple application which will mark the states in India depending to state name.

So, I started with experimenting as the following example.

It works good if I set the `displayMode : 'markers'` but according to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Overview) states can be display as regions.

But, its not working. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

      function drawMarkersMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['State'],
        ['West Bengal'],
      ]);

      var options = {
        region: 'IN',
        displayMode: 'regions',
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set your options to `resolution: 'provinces'`

Here is the code (working):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

      function drawMarkersMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['State', 'Data'],
        ['West Bengal', 5],
      ]);

      var options = {
        region: 'IN',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: 'provinces',
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```